# scala.concurrent.Future wrapper for java.util.concurrent.Future

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, playframework-2.1, future

I'm using Play Framework 2.1.1 with an external java library that produces a java.util.concurrent.Future result. I'm using the scala future's as opposed to Akka which I think is the right thing to do as of Play 2.1. How can I wrap the java.util.concurrent.Future up into a scala.concurrent.Future while still keeping the code non-blocking?

```
def geConnection() : Connection = {
  // blocking with get
  connectionPool.getConnectionAsync().get(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}
```

The above code returns a connection but uses a get so it becomes blocking

```
def getConnectionFuture() : Future[Connection] = {
  future {
    // how to remove blocking get and return a scala future?
    connectionPool.getConnectionAsync().get(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  }
}
```

Ideally I want a scala function that returns the connection as a future like the code above but without the code blocking via the get. What else do I need to put into the function to make it non blocking.

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using? As of 2.10.x, Scala adopted Akka's Future as its own.

Comment: Play 2.1.1 uses Scala 2.10.0 under the covers

Answer (score 21):

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Future => JFuture}
import scala.concurrent.{Future => SFuture}
```

You can't wrap [`JFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) with [`SFuture`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) without blocking since there is a callback in `SFuture` (`onComplete`) and there is only blocking `get` in `JFuture`.

All you can do is to create additional thread and block it with `get`, then complete [`Promise`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Promise) with result of `get`.

```scala
val jfuture: JFuture[T] = ???
val promise = Promise[T]()
new Thread(new Runnable { def run() { promise.complete(Try{ jfuture.get }) }}).start
val future = promise.future
```

You could check `isDone` in endless loop, but I don't think it is better then blocking.

Comment: Agreed.  Total shame that the Java future does not support some sort of completion listener/observer for a callback

Comment: @cmbaxter if you use Guava, there is `ListenableFuture`

Comment: So I was thinking along the lines of a callback for the java peice, that when finished, would have its result up in scala future. Looking around there are examples of callbacks implemented in Java (http://technology.amis.nl/2009/02/19/asynchronous-processing-in-java-applications-leveraging-those-multi-cores/) but wasn't sure how to roll this into Play 2.1. Optimistically I was hoping for a simple wrapper but it doesn't look thats doable, and a java callback within a scala function looks the way to go.

Comment: I'm curious, what's wrong with `future { jfuture.get }`? Why you used an extra thread combined with `Promise`?

Comment: @PetrPudlák: it'll block thread in your thread pull. If you have a configured `ExecutionContext` for such futures it's fine, but default `ExecutionContext` contains [as many](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L68) threads as you have processors.

Comment: @senia, I have opened a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21190140/1714997) about why `future { jfuture.get }` is not enough.

Answer (score 7):

```
Future {
  blocking {
    jfuture.get
  }
}
```

This lets the ExecutionContext know that what you are doing is going to block, giving it a chance to allocate more threads. If you do not include `blocking { }` then you may run out of threads.

Comment: You might want to provide details on what the pros/cons of this are. Is it the exact same as discussed above (in comments e.g. from @senia)

Comment: Sorry about that. Added a comment to explain the use of "blocking".

Comment: And if you do 'blocking' then you could end up with tens of thousands of threads on high load. Be careful -- 'blocking' is no magic!

Answer (score 2):

```
     import java.util.concurrent.{Future => JFuture}
     import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
     import scala.concurrent.Future
     import scala.util.Try

     object JFuture2SFuture {
        val jFuture: JFuture[Int] = ???
        val promise = Promise[Int]()
        Future { promise.complete(Try(jFuture.get)) } //it is non blocking 
        val sFuture:Future[Int] = promise.future

     }
```

Comment: The comment says 'it is non-blocking' but this looks like it would block the executing thread to me. `Try.apply` is a by-name call but that doesn't imply it would execute asynchronously. Promise.complete is similarly blocking. This does wrap the java future's `.get`. in an async scala `Future`, but it would still block the executing thread, similar to `Future { Thread.sleep(10000); }`

Comment: Yes, It will block executing thread but not calling thread. That's intention not block calling thread.

Answer (score -1):

The [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) library provides converters between java8 and Scala Futures.

Specifically, you can use [`FutureConverters.toScala(connectionPool.getConnectionAsync())`](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/compat/java8/FutureConverters.scala#L78) to convert the `java.util.concurrent.Future` to `scala.concurrent.Future`

Comment: This answer is misleading. scala-java8-compat enables converting from `java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage` to `scala.concurrent.Future`. There is no "proper" way to convert a Java Future to Scala Future.