# Concurrent requests with ScalaWS (Play Framework)

Tags: scala, playframework

```
def resolve(url: String): Future[WSResponse] = ws.url(url).withFollowRedirects(true).get()

def validateAllLinks(links: List[String]) = ???
```

How would you solve the second function?

I have tried traverse, Future.sequence, Await ...

This was my most recent try:

```
def validateAllLinks(links: List[String]) = links.map(link =>
    Await.result(resolve(link), Duration.create(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
)
```

The problem with this approach:

1. i get TimeoutExceptions and MaxRedirectException that i don't want to try/catch
2. I don't think the solution would be concurrent, even if it worked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feel free to use `Future.sequence`, they will be running in parallel:

```
def validateAllLinks(links: List[String]): Future[List[WSResponse]] = 
    Future.sequence(links.map(resolve))
```

If you call `Await.result` after `Future.sequence`, it will wait for the **parallel operations** to complete:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
def validateAllLinks(links: List[String]): List[WSResponse] = 
    Await.result(Future.sequence(links.map(resolve)), 10 seconds)
```

But please keep in mind that `Await.result` is considered a bad practice, you should try to return the `Future`, and let the client decide how to handle it.

A little more detail about why it's a bad practice:

1. https://monix.io/docs/2x/best-practices/blocking.html
2. https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/4-concurrency-parallelism.md#45-should-not-block

Comment: Correct, however there is a problem in this approach that it doesn't allow to handle timeouts and errors for individual requests. Probably this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466889/run-multiple-futures-in-parallel-return-default-value-on-timeout helps.

Comment: Right, my solution was to make it concurrent. To handle the timeouts, `ws.url(url).withRequestTimeout(timeout)` should be used in resolve method. And `resolve(..).map(..).recovery(..)` should be used to understand which ones fail and which ones succeed.