# Why new thread instead of future {...}

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, blocking, future

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215663/1714997) instructs how to convert `java.util.concurrent.Future` into `scala.concurrent.Future`, while managing where the blocking will occur:

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.{Future => JFuture}
import scala.concurrent.{Future => SFuture}

val jfuture: JFuture[T] = ???
val promise = Promise[T]()
new Thread(
  new Runnable {
    def run() { promise.complete(Try{ jfuture.get }) }
  }
).start
val future = promise.future
```

My queston is the same as a question asked in the comments:

> what's wrong with `future { jfuture.get }`? Why you used an extra thread combined with Promise?

It was answered as follows:

> it'll block thread in your thread pull. If you have a configured ExecutionContext for such futures it's fine, but default ExecutionContext contains as many threads as you have processors.

I'm not sure I understand the explanation. To reiterate:

What's wrong with `future { jfuture.get }`? Isn't blocking inside a future the same as manually creating a new Thread and blocking there? If not, how is it different?

Comment: what exactly do you not understand? What does blocking of a thread means?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I have somewhat revised my question: What's wrong with `future { jfuture.get }`? Isn't blocking inside a future the same as manually creating a new Thread and blocking there? If not, how is it different?

Comment: Yes blocking inside a future is AS BAD as manually creating a new Thread and blocking there. The idea of converting to `scala.concurrent.Future` is to avoid blocking entirely by using `onComplete` instead of `get`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is almost no difference between `future { jfuture.get }` and `future { future { jfuture.get }}`.

There are as many treads in default thread pool as many you have processors.

With `jfuture.get` you'll get 1 thread blocked.

Let's assume you have 8 processors. Also let's suppose each `jfuture.get` takes 10 seconds. Now create 8 `future { jfuture.get }`.

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(_: Date)

val startTime = new Date
(1 to 8) map {_ => future{ Thread.sleep(10000) }}
future{
  2+2
  println(s"2+2 done. Start time: ${format(startTime)}, end time: ${format(new Date)}")
}

// 2+2 done. Start time: 20:48:18, end time: 20:48:28
```

10 seconds is a little too long for `2+2` evaluation.

All other `future`s and all actors on the same execution context will be stopped for 10 seconds.

With additional execution context:

```
object BlockingExecution {
  val executor = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new ForkJoinPool(20))
}

def blockingFuture[T](f: => T) = {
  future( f )(BlockingExecution.executor)
}

val startTime = new Date
(1 to 8) map {_ => blockingFuture{ Thread.sleep(10000) }}
future{
  2+2
  println(s"2+2 done. Start time: ${format(startTime)}, end time: ${format(new Date)}")
}

// 2+2 done. Start time: 21:26:18, end time: 21:26:18
```

You could implement `blockingFuture` using `new Thread(new Runnable {...`, but additional execution context allows you to limit threads count.

Comment: There's no inherent reason that the future that computes 2+2 needs to be executed after the other futures. (You have simply asked for 9 things to be computed asynchronously.) If you change `Future { Thread.sleep(10000) }` to `Future { blocking { Thread.sleep(10000) } }`, the 2+2 future will execute immediately. My understanding is that the `blocking` method gives a hint so that the thread pool moves on to process other futures first. I haven't found any good resources describing exactly what is going on here.

Comment: @Patrick that is true. when using `blocking` the global thread pool will spawn a new thread for that computation so that it doesn't run out of threads. More info here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html See the "Blocking" section

Answer (score 7):

It's actually quite simple. `scala.concurrent.Promise` is a concrete implementation of a `Future`, destined to be an asynchronous computation.

When you want to convert, with `jfuture.get`, you are running a blocking computation and outputting an immediately resolved `scala.concurrent.Future`.

The `Thread` will block until the computation inside `jfuture` is complete. The `get` method is blocking.

Blocking means nothing else will happen inside that `Thread` until the computation is complete. You are essentially monopolising the `Thread` with something that looks like a `while` loop intermittently checking for results.

```
while (!isDone() && !timeout) {
   // check if the computation is complete
}
```

Specifically:

```
val jfuture: JFuture[T] = ??? // some blocking task
```

When blocking cannot be avoided, the common practice is to spawn a `new Thread` and a `new Runnable` or `new Callable` to allow the computation to execute/monopolize a child thread.

In the example @senia gave:

```
new Thread(new Runnable { def run() {
  promise.complete(Try{ jfuture.get })
}}).start
```

How is this different than `future {jfuture.get}`? It doesn't block your default `ExecutionContext`, provided by Scala, which has as many threads as the processors of the machine.

That would mean all other futures in your code will always have to wait for `future { jfuture.get }` to complete, since the entire context is blocked.

Comment: I am under the impression that spawning a new thread and executing `somethingThatBlocks()` in it is the same as future(somethingThatBlocks()). My question is mostly about whether that is true, and if not, how is it different?

Comment: so in general it is not recommended to have lengthy computations inside a future with default execution context?

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis: no, default execution context has a thread pool and chooses one of them to run the code inside of the future. It does not span new thread every time because creating a thread is an expensive operation and threads are a limited resource.